# Passing allocatable arrays to subroutine with fixed dimension dummy variables

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am writing some code, in which I need to use some modules given to me by my guide. Now, in these modules, there are subroutines which take dummy arrays, which have a fixed dimension. However, I need to pass some allocatable arrays to these functions.

What I want to know is whether there is a way to pass allocatable arrays as arguments to subroutines or functions whose dummy arguments are of a fixed dimension.

Here is the actual subroutine which is to be used:

```
function crosscorr(x, y, n, k)
! Cross-correlation of array x and y for a given time shift k.
implicit none
integer :: n, k
real(8), dimension(0:n-1) :: x, y
real(8) crosscorr
if (k.ge.0) then
    crosscorr = dot_product(x(0:n-1-k), y(k:n-1))
else
    crosscorr = dot_product(x(-k:n-1), y(0:n-1+k))
endif
end function crosscorr
!!!---------------------------------------------------------------------!!!


!!!---------------------------------------------------------------------!!!
subroutine xcorr_full(x, y, n, shift, delay, ccmax, ccpol)
! Cross-correlation of array x and y.
! Return time shift, correlation coefficient, and polarity at maximum correlation.
implicit none
integer :: n, shift, delay, ccpol
real(8), dimension(0:n-1) :: x, y
real(8) :: cc, ccmax, ccmin
integer :: k, kmin
!f2py intent(in)  :: x, y, n, shift
!f2py intent(out) :: delay, ccmax, ccpol
!f2py intent(hide):: c, k, kmin, ccmin

shift = 1
ccmax = 0
ccmin = 0
kmin = 0
do k = -n+1,n-1,shift
    cc = crosscorr(x,y,n,k)   
    if (cc.gt.ccmax) then
        ccmax = cc
        delay = k
    endif
    if (cc.lt.ccmin) then
        ccmin = cc
        kmin = k
    endif
enddo
if (ccmax.gt.-ccmin) then
    ccpol = 1
else
    ccmax = -ccmin
    delay = kmin
    ccpol = -1
endif
ccmax = ccmax/sqrt( dot_product(x,x) * dot_product(y,y) )

end subroutine xcorr_full
```

And here is the code from the program:

```
real(8), allocatable :: v(:,:),vref_win(:),v_win(:)

allocate(vref_win(0:ending-starting))
allocate(v_win(0:ending-starting))
vref_win(0:ending-starting)=v(starting-1:ending-1,ref_t)


do i=0,n_stn-1
    v_win(0:ending-starting)=v(starting-1:ending-1,i)
    call xcorr_full(vref_win,v_win,ending-starting+1,1,t_corr,r,sign)
enddo
```

The whole program is a bit long, so I am not posting it here, but all the variables are properly defined, the array v has data, and is indexed correctly

This is the error I am getting if I just try to pass the arrays normally:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.
```

I am using the `-fcheck=all` flag while compiling using gfortran(v7.3.0)

My question is however not specifically dependent on this program. Any explanation for this, as well as any reading resources, would be very helpful since I could not find any proper resources which could help answer this exact question.

Comment: Yes I di get an error. Should I post it here?

Comment: I updated the question. Please check

Comment: Can you identify the line of code that is generating the error, through the debugger or something?

Comment: This question is what I required. Thanks @francescalus. Please close this question if necessary. That question did not come up in searches or suggestions, so I am sorry for not looking more thoroughly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179773/discussion-between-yuki-kuroshita-and-rodrigo-rodrigues).